# Delay Injecting angular service until function is run

Tags: angularjs

I am running into a dependency catch 22.  Service A must run before service B to install some method hooks that service B will use.  However, I want one of the installed methods to use service B.  Service A and B will both initialize before any other code is run, my init logic is responsible for that.

The easiest thing for me to do would be to make service A install a method that uses service B, but does not actually load service B until the method installed by service A is run.  Thus A can run before B, installing all the hooks required, but can still use service B when the appropriate methods is called, at which time it's safe for B to initialize since A has already done it's thing.

Is there a convenient way to do this in Angular?  It looks like the $inject service might do this, but if so I'm not certain how to make it work.

edit: I didn't add psudo code originally because the example I have uses restangular and would get confusing.  I've tried to come up with some stupid psudo-code example of something similar, though my actual situation is not quite as straight forward, I don't get circle dependencies, just odd behavior if the dependencies are not right.

```
angular.model('myProj.common').factory('RestCaller', funciton(){

    var route:

    return{ route: function(route) {
        var get: function() { //does stuff };
        var save: function() //does stuff
        var getPermissions function(PermissionService) {
            PermissionService.getPermissions(route);
        }
    };
  });

  angular.model('myProj.common').factory('PermissionService', funciton(RestCaller){

    return{
              getPermissions: function(route)  {
                     return RestCaller.route(route).get();
              }
           }
   )};
```

Here restCaller uses PermissionService for one method; but PermissionService uses RestCaller.  If I can inject PermissionService into the getPermission method I'm fine and this works.  If I have to inject PermissionService into the Factory it doesn't work; since both are dependent on each other.

Comment: Could you add some pseudo code or something to make the steps more straightforward? $injector isn't too hard to use, you can just call var serviceB = $injector.get('serviceB') at anytime (in a call back, after a promise resolves, etc), if that is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not misunderstanding your question, is this what you are looking to achieve?

```
app.factory('factoryName', function () {
  return {
    getA = //Your A Logic Here\\
    getB: getB
  };

  function getB() {
    return //Your B Logic Here\\;
  }
});
```

Comment: somewhat yes, except that the logic is very different.  it would not make sense for getA and getB to be part of the same factory.  They both belong in different factories based off of codeing conventions we've already defined.